# Is there a way to do material pagination on a material table without using MatTableDataSource? Angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there a way to do material pagination on a table without using MatTableDataSource? Every example I see online has me using MatTableDataSource, but I'm not sure how to actually use it.
I'm populating my material table from a database table.

```
users: any[] = [];
displayData = [];
dataSource = [];
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private userService: UserService,
    private router: Router,
    private httpClient: HttpClient
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._getUsers();
    
  }

private _getUsers() {
    this.userService;
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe((data) => {
      this.users = data.users;
      this.displayData = data.users;      
      this.dataSource = this.users;
      
    });
```

```
<div class="users">
  <app-extend-table #usersTable
                       [header]="header"
                       [data]="displayData"
                       [columns]="columns">
  </app-extend-table>
  <!-- <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator> -->
  
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, your question is not clear, if you mean can you use pagination separately, yes you can. you can add separate pagination and add (page) event on it and just split and show the corresponding items from your data list.

Comment: Yes. That is what I'm mean. Doing it separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add `[length]="users?.length"` and just listen to the `page` output event of the `mat-pagination` and show the corresponding items in the table

like this.

```
<mat-paginator (page)="pageChanged($event)" [length]="users?.length" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

**in ts**

```
 // import PageEvent from angulat material pagination
pageChanged(event: PageEvent) {
const users = [...this.users];
   this.dataSource = users.splice((event.pageIndex - 1) * event.pageSize, event.pageSize );
}
```

here is the working example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-adrxts?file=app/table-pagination-example.ts

Comment: I'm going to give this a try. Will report back shortly. Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting an error on event.pageIndex and event.pageSize stating that property does not exist.

Comment: did you import PageEvent from the material/pagination

Comment: import { PageEvent } from '@angular/material/paginator';

Comment: Oh...sorry about that. I noticed this shortly after I posted my response. I did forget to import PageEvent.  The event is firing(I have a console.log in the event), but doesn't seem to be changing the page. Since I currently have 4 items in table, I adjusted my pageSizeOptions to test if I had 2 items per page.

Comment: No....it's not working. I set it for 2 items per page since I only have 4 total items. Give me a sec and let me post my current code....

Comment: yeah it will be helpfull

Comment: also can you put the `app-extend-table` component ts code?

Comment: @ProfessorD1906_4 I have added the stackblitz example. I have commented whole code for your case. please replace the commented code blocks on your side and check. I think it should work on your side/

Comment: I got it to work. Thanks! Greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to help. No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an update snippit ....
TS file

```
import { PageEvent } from '@angular/material/paginator';

@ViewChild(PageEvent, { static: false }) paginator: PageEvent;
displayData = [];
dataSource = [];
public list = new MatTableDataSource();
pageEvent: PageEvent;


constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    private router: Router,
    private httpClient: HttpClient
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._getUsers();
    
  }

private _getUsers() {
    this.userService;
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe((data) => {
      this.users = data.users;
      this.displayData = data.users;      
      this.dataSource = this.users;
      
    });

pageChanged(event: PageEvent) {
    const list = this.users    
    console.log('list: ' + list);
    this.dataSource = list.splice((event.pageIndex - 1) * event.pageSize, event.pageSize);
    console.log(this.dataSource)
  }
```

HTML file

```
<div class="users">
  <app-extend-table #usersTable
                       [header]="header"
                       [data]="displayData"
                       [columns]="columns">
  </app-extend-table>
<!-- "users?.length" -->
  <mat-paginator (page)="pageChanged($event)"
               [length]=  "2"             
               [pageSizeOptions]="[2, 4, 6]"
               showFirstLastButtons>

</mat-paginator>
  
</div>
```

app-extend-table component

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.tableData.sort = this.sort;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   
    this.columns.forEach((col) => {
      let pair = Object.entries(col);
      this.columnKeyValuePairs.push(pair[0]);
      this.displayedColumns.push(pair[0][0]);
    });
  }

  ngOnChanges(old) {
    if (old.data) {
      this.tableData = new MatTableDataSource<any>(old.data.currentValue);
      this.tableData.sort = this.sort;
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you also include the `app-extend-table` component.ts code?

Comment: Just included it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the Same use case. Tried @Ashot Aleqsanyan Answer, found an issue with that-
using `this.dataSource = users.splice((event.pageIndex - 1) * event.pageSize, event.pageSize );` will show same number of rows as pageSize even in the last pageIndex.

For Example: pageSize selected is 5 and data has 6 rows, then the expected behaviour is that first page should show 5 and last page should show the remaining which is 1 row, but it shows 5 instead by duplicating previous rows(2-5).

Using `this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(rows.splice((event.pageIndex * event.pageSize), event.pageSize ));` fixed the issue.

here is the working Example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-adrxts-7npzwj?file=app%2Ftable-pagination-example.ts